# Why window.maximize() called in main process and render process are different from the animation on macos?

Tags: javascript, macos, animation, electron

when I maximize the `window` in render process with `remote.getCurrentWindow().maximize()` the animation of `window` max isn't smooth as I use ipcRenderer send a message to main process to `window.maximize()`.

It's on MacOS 10.14.4 and electron 4.1.4.

```
document.getElementById('maxrender').addEventListener('click', () => {
  // the animation is not smooth
  if (currentWindow.isMaximized()) {
    currentWindow.unmaximize();
  } else {
      currentWindow.maximize();
  }
})
document.getElementById('maxmain').addEventListener('click', () => {
  // the app will receive this message and call the same function
  // the animation is smooth
  ipc.send('window-max')
})
```

click 'max with window' and 'max with ipc', the smooth of animation is quite different

Comment: the whole project https://github.com/Aura-zx/electron-quick-start

Answer (score 0):

I have created an issue [#17858](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17858) on electron community.

Simply, the `remote` call is `synchronous` and will block render process for a few `ms`. So the animation isn't smooth as messaging with `asynchronous` ipcRenderer.